# deriving ODE for the Resolvent Kernel of a diffusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have been reading a book by Jeanblanc, Yor, Chesney (2009) "Mathematical Methods for Financial Markets" and ran into the section on resolvent kernels which is very terse (Section $5.3.6$, page $277$). I do not understand the connection between resolvent kernel of a diffusion (denoted below by $R_{\lambda}(x,y)$) and the following ODE:

> $\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x)\frac{\partial^2R_{\lambda}}{\partial x^2} + b(x) \frac{\partial R_{\lambda}}{\partial x} - \lambda R_{\lambda}=0$

where $d X_t = b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dW_t$ is a diffusion process and $W_t$ denotes a standard brownian motion

---

Here is the excerpt from the book that I am trying to understand (below $X_t$ is a time homogeneous diffusion proces satisfying $d X_t = b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dW_t$ with $X_0=x$).

> **Resolvent Kernel**
>
> The resolvent of a Markov process X is a family of operators $f \rightarrow R_{\lambda}f$ 
>   $$ R_{\lambda}f(x)=\mathbb{E}_x\left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{\lambda t} f(X_t) dt  \right)$$
>   The resolvent kernel of a diffusion is the density (with respect to Lebesgue measure) of the resolvent operator, i.e., the Laplace transform in t of the transition density $p_t(x,y)$ :
>   $$ R_{\lambda}(x,y) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} p_t{(x,y)}dt$$
>   It satisfies 
>   $$ \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x)\frac{\partial^2R_{\lambda}}{\partial x^2} + b(x) \frac{\partial R_{\lambda}}{\partial x} - \lambda R_{\lambda}=0 $$
>   and $R_{\lambda}(x,x)=1$.

**Question**: How to obtain that ODE from the definition of $R_{\lambda}(x,y)$?

This is probably trivial (so I apologize in advance if that is indeed the case), but since I am self-studying this there is nobody I can consult.

**A related issue**:
The authors then use the solutions to this equation to obtain expressions for the Laplace transforms of the first hitting time in terms of solutions to the above ODE.
$$ \mathbb{E_x}(e^{-\lambda T_{y}}) = \Phi_{\lambda \uparrow}(x)/\Phi_{\lambda \uparrow}(y) \text{ if x<y}$$
where $\Phi_{\lambda \uparrow}(x)$ is an increasing function that satisfies the above ODE. A result which I also have hard time understanding...

Comment: The generator is given by $$L=\frac{1}{2}\sigma(x)^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + b(x)\frac{d}{dx}$$ Usually $R_{\lambda}$ is simply defined to be the inverse of $L-\lambda I$. But even if you don't know that you can check directly that it is true: Almost by definition of the generator, it follows that $p_t(x,y)$ is the fundamental solution to the PDE $\partial_t p = Lp$, i.e., the solution from initial data $\delta_x$. Thus $$LR_{\lambda}-\lambda R_{\lambda}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}(Lp_t)(x,y)-\lambda e^{-\lambda t}p_t(x,y)dt=\int_0^{\infty}\partial_t(e^{-\lambda t}p_t(x,y))dt=\delta(x-y)$$

Comment: I see, thanks!  Just to clarify, $I$ in $L-\lambda I$ the identity operator, right? Any idea how to use then the expression for $R_{\lambda}(x,y)$ to obtain the Laplace transform of first hitting time?

Comment: Yes it's the identity. BTW, $R_{\lambda}$ should be the inverse of $\lambda I-L$, I missed a negative sign at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know how to use then the resolvent to find the Laplace transform of the first hitting time as stated by the authors?